# Merging a png on a polygon in php

Tags: php, image

I'm confused, i try to simply draw a polygon and put on it, like a layer a png with transparencies.. Without any succes. One time the background is blak, one time the polygone become invisible..

here is my php code :

```
header ("Content-type: image/png");

// The png layer
$png = imagecreatefrompng("./300.png"); 
imagealphablending($png, false);
$largeur_source = imagesx($png);
$hauteur_source = imagesy($png);


// The polygon
$polygon_image = imagecreate($largeur_source,$hauteur_source);
$polygon_image_background = imagecolorallocate($polygon_image, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($polygon_image, $polygon_image_background); // On rend le fond blanc transparent
$polygon_color = imagecolorallocate($polygon_image,100, 200, 225);

$polygon = array(0,0,
                 982,0,
                 982,48,
                 6,48,
                 6,53,
                 0,47,
                 0,0
                 );

imagefilledpolygon($polygon_image , $polygon , 6 , $polygon_color);

imagecopymerge($polygon_image, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source,100); // black !
//imagecopy($polygon_image, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source); // transparent but no polygon..

imagepng($polygon_image);
```

I have googeled during hours, testing lot of things but...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why exactly your code does not work as expected, but let me propose a slightly different approach:

First, create a true color image instead of just a "normal" image:

```
$polygon_image = imagecreatetruecolor($largeur_source, $hauteur_source);
```

Then draw the polygon etc. like this:

```
// ...

$polygon = array(/*...*/);

// Make the whole image transparent
imagefill($polygon_image, 0, 0, $polygon_image_background);

// Draw the polygon
imagefilledpolygon($polygon_image, $polygon, 6, $polygon_color);

// Enable alpha blending
imagealphablending($polygon_image, true);

// Initialize the brush with the png
imagesetbrush($polygon_image, $png);

// Merge the two images by drawing the brush (png) exactly once
// right in the middle of the polygon image:
imageline($polygon_image, $largeur_source / 2, $hauteur_source / 2, $largeur_source / 2, $hauteur_source / 2, IMG_COLOR_BRUSHED);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused here :D