# Translate 3D object onto 2D space

Tags: php, math

I am trying to find the math required to translate (x,y,z) into (x,y) so I can create boxes with php.  All points will be on the grid and there are no rotations.

I've tried out this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955134/379249 which gets me part of the way there but I need to figure out the points of the polygons

For example, I have a large box shown in red below.

[image: boxes]

I need to be able to give it the dimensions of either width, length, height and starting point or I can give it all four points that make up each face.

I need to translate those to make it appear 3D which is what I'm tripped up on.

Once the red box is created, I would also need to be able to create other boxes using the same function such as the green, blue or orange one.

I can create the code, but I am stuck on the math to do the translations.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT** **

Thanks to @user2464424 I am able to get it very close.  Below is my code.

And my generated image.

```
<?php
function RotatePoint($sin,$cos,$x,$y) {
    return array($x*$cos - $y*$sin, $y*$cos + $x*$sin);
}

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 200, $white);

$brown = imagecolorallocate($im, 120, 53, 31);
$green = imagecolorallocate($im, 23, 255, 65);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 31, 23, 255);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 185, 23);

function draw_box(&$image, $color, $start, $width, $length, $height)
{
    $camx = 80;
    $camy = 240;
    $camz = 40;

    $yaw = 10;
    $pitch = 20;
    $sy = sin(-$yaw); $cy = cos(-$yaw); $sp = sin(-$pitch); $cp = cos(-$pitch);

    $start_x = $start[0];
    $start_y = $start[1];
    $start_z = $start[2];

    // Draw 6 faces
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
        switch ($i)
        {
            case 0:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z+$height)
                );
                break;
            case 1:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height)
                );
                break;
            case 2:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z),
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z+$height)
                );
                break;
            case 3:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z+$height)
                );
                break;
            case 4:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height),
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z+$height)
                );
                break;
            case 5:
                $face = array(
                    array($start_x, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y, $start_z),
                    array($start_x+$width, $start_y+$length, $start_z),
                    array($start_x, $start_y+$length, $start_z)
                );
                break;
        }


        $polygon = array();
        foreach ($face as $point)
        {
            $x = $point[0] - $camx; 
            $y = $point[1] - $camy; 
            $z = $point[2] - $camz;

            $rot = RotatePoint($sy,$cy,$x,$y);
            $x = $rot[0];
            $y = $rot[1];

            $rot = RotatePoint($sp,$cp,$z,$y);
            $z = $rot[0];
            $y = $rot[1];

            $polygon[] = $x;
            $polygon[] = $z;
        }

        imagepolygon($image, $polygon, 4, $color);
    }   
}

draw_box($im, $brown, array(0, 0, 0), 80, 80, 80);

draw_box($im, $green, array(0, 0, 0), 40, 40, 40);

draw_box($im, $blue, array(0, 0, 40), 30, 20, 10);

draw_box($im, $orange, array(60, 0, 0), 15, 40, 80);

imagepng($im, './image.png');

imagedestroy($im);
?>
<img src="image.png">
```

[image]

A couple issues.

1: How do I get the origin of the axis at the bottom, right now it's upside down on the right.

2: Say I always want to produce it on a 400x400 image, how would I make sure it doesn't go off that or be able to scale up?

3: If the container is 40x40x40 or 10x100x100, how could I adjust the origin so it's always at the bottom of the image and the box scales to fit?

**EDIT** **

Here is a link to the final code:
https://gist.github.com/rzfarrell/3a9e5046dcfd6bd2d2f4bfa1a34b21ef

Makes this:
[image]

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is orthographic projection, is that correct?

Comment: There are *bazillions* of ways to project 3D onto 2D. If you have not alreadym then , take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection. Also, translations are easy (just do x' = x + delta, etc.). Rotations are much harder: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)

Comment: @user2464424 yes orthographic projection is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of the orthographic projection of a 3D point against a free camera in 3D space is to move and rotate the camera so that it ends up being a) centered at the origin and b) not rotated. The catch is that all the points that make up the 3D world must rigidly follow the camera as it is being transformed.

This usually boils down to a two-step process:

1) first, translate the point by the origin-camera vector inverted:

```
$x = $pointx - $camx; $y = $pointy - $camy; $z = $pointz - $camz;
```

2) then, rotate the point around the origin by the pitch and yaw angles of the camera negated (possibly in radians):

```
$sy = sin(-$yaw); $cy = cos(-$yaw); $sp = sin(-$pitch); $cp = cos(-$pitch);

function RotatePoint($sin,$cos,$x,$y) {
    return array($x*$cos - $y*$sin, $y*$cos + $x*$sin);
}

$rot = RotatePoint($sy,$cy,$x,$y);
$x = $rot[0];
$y = $rot[1];

$rot = RotatePoint($sp,$cp,$z,$y);
$z = $rot[0];
$y = $rot[1];
```

And you are done. Now, `$x` and `$z` represent the coordinates of the 2D point in the camera plane from the center of the camera and `$y` is the perpendicular distance of the point to the camera plane.

If you want to output a picture you might want to scale and limit the coordinates to fit the image size which is trivial. One thing that you must consider is to ignore all points that have `y<=0` because it means they are behind the camera.

Comment: thanks!  I've gotten some working code and updated my question with it but have a couple issues to solve still.

Comment: @bones You are welcome, but pay more attention, there is confusion in some parts. For a start, the camera orientation angles are supposed to be in radians. Use the [`deg2rad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php) function to do the conversion. Then, remember that once the point coordinates are transformed, you can do whatever you want with them. For example, you can negate `$z` to flip the result upside down. Also, because the 'screen' is an image that has (0,0) on the top left corner, you want to add an offset like `= $CanvasHalfWidth+$x;` and `= $CanvasHalfHeight-$z;`

Comment: @bones To scale, you can also multiply `$x` and `$z` by some factor that can be called zoom. Once you do the modifications try camera position (-25, -50, 100) yaw=deg2rad(-35) and pitch = deg2rad(35). I tried with these parameters and got a nice more or less centered image.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That worked I just got to place around with some sort of auto scale based on the largest box dimensions

Comment: @bones Glad to hear! Would you mind sharing your current code for completeness? Even a simplified one.

Comment: I added a link and example image of the final solution to the main question.  I was able to figure out how to scale and center the boxes.